# Trying to set magento developing version on subdomain

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I'm trying to set Magento on a development subdomain and update it to 1.9., but it keeps me redirecting to old domain.

This is wat I did:

- I installed a clean version of 1.9 (without setting up the database) in my subdomain directory
- Copied all custom files from production to development (skins, modules etc)
- Duplicated the database (Magento 1.8)
- Copied local.xml to development and pointed to new database
- Replaced al secure en unsecure path's to http://dev.domain.com
- chmod -R o+w media var
- chmod o+w app/etc
- Visiting dev.domain.com

For some reason, It keeps me redirecting to my old domain.

Comment: check once htaccess file having redirect 301 or in cpanel, check the redirect option

Answer (score 2):

1. Clean the cache, the config is cached
2. restart your browser, your browser caches the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; I had to change the APC caching prefix in local.xml. I did cleared the cache via the APC console, but apparently that don't work because of the prefix.